# Using ngx-translate for dynamic data

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngx-translate

I have object paginationShow:

```
export class PaginationShow {
FromEntries:number;
ToEntries:number;
TotalEntries:number}
```

In Html :

```
<p>{{'Table.ShowPagingEntries' | translate : paginationShow }}</p>
```

In Json File:

```
"ShowPagingEntries":"Showing {{FromEntries}} to {{ToEntries}} of{{TotalEntries}} entries",
```

When i change data of PaginationShow the data show in Html is not change follow by PaginationShow. How i can using dynamic data for this. Please Help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<p>{{getTranslation('Table.ShowPagingEntries',paginationShow)}}</p>
```

In your component, you can add `private translateService: TranslateService` to your constructor.

```
getTranslation(key: string, params: PaginationShow) {
   return params ? this.translateService.instant(key, {TotalEntries: params.TotalEntries,FromEntries:params.FromEntries:params,ToEntries:params.}) :'' 
}
```

Comment: I think it's not recommended to call the function directly inside the HTML template, for some performance reason